# Meaning of 結果を出す in this paragraph

Tags: meaning

I am trying to understand the following paragraph, especially the last sentence

> 年収400万位にはしたいのだけど、会社にデジタル化しようと持ちかけても変化なし、SNSに書いても全く改善されない。何とか結果を出そうとするがやっても結局給料があがらないので転職すべきか、しっかりここで結果を出すべきか迷っている

I don't quite get the idea of "結果を出す" here, in my understanding it roughly means "get results" but it does not seem to fit into the context.

Can someone help translate this paragraph into English?

Answer (score 2):

In the quoted sentence, 結果を出す means *to accomplish (something)* or  *to produce notable outcome*.

In concrete terms, for a football player (of some type), 結果を出す means scoring or assisting goals; for an academic, publishing papers; for a salaryman, leading a successful project.

So the speaker is undecided between changing jobs or staying to get something done (which would put him/her in a better position in the company or in the job market).

---

My impression is that this usage is recent. Cf. [a chiebukuro question](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1136695126)